# All news items from tt_news are shown

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I'm new to typo3 and I wound to setup tt_news. I followed the next plan:

1. Install the plugin
2. Made a folder "News Items"
3. With the News Admin plugin made two categories and added a news item in both categories
4. Made a new normal content page
5. Added a contend field as plugin
6. Selected at "other settings" the folder
7. Selected at general settings the list view

At "categorie selection" under "general settings" the categories I made in the folder are not selectable under "Available Items:"? Therefore probably the website show now all news item from all categories on my content page.

Comment: Try to move category to the Storage Folder and chec if it helps, also point tge Storage Folder in the root page's properties, consult your problem reading the `General Records Storage Pid` topic, we can't guess what's wrong if you can't

Comment: Your correct by disabling the "Use General record storage page" at the plugin settings it is solved

Comment: You also should consider using the extension `news` instead of the older `tt_news`. `tt_news` is kept alive, but not likely to be improved very much, `news` probably will be improved. Also, templates are are more flexibel in `news` since it uses fluid.